# Shift some lines of text to the far right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, justification

How can I shift some lines of text to the far right, as in the following figure?

[image]

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
A paragraph of text.

\bigskip
Author\\
Place\\
Date\\

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

flush a left aligned tabular to the right:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
A paragraph of text.

\begin{flushright}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
Author\\
Place\\
Date    
  \end{tabular}
\end{flushright}


\end{document}
```